# Area using definite integral

Tags: integration

I am trying to find out the area of lens using definite integral. (the area of the shaded region)

[image]

The area of lens is $$R^2\theta+r^2\alpha-2\times\Delta$$
where,$\theta$ and $\alpha$ are the angles of triangles and sides are $R$ and $r$.
The third side of the triangle is $d$, which is the distance between center.
Suppose the lens is formed by two circles of radius $R$ and $r$.
Let the equation circles be $$x^2+y^2=R^2....(1)$$
and $$x^2+y^2+2rx=0.....(2)$$
 From $(1)$, $$y=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}....(3)$$ 
and from $(2)$,$$y=\sqrt{-x^2-2rx}....(4)$$ 
The integral of $(3)$ is $$ 1/2 (x \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} + r^2 tan^{-1}(x/\sqrt{r^2 - x^2})) + constant $$
similarly the integral of $(4)$ is $$\ 1/3 (r + 2 x)\times \sqrt{-r (r + 2 x)} + constant$$
I can not not understand how this rather bizarre expression simplify to the area of lens .
  Thank you.

Comment: Your question would be much more understandable if you stated the area *of the cross-section* ! Also tell us what $\Delta$ is.

Comment: @YvesDaoust   $\Delta$ is the area of the triangle with sides R,r and d

Comment: Your integral computations are wrong. There is no logarithm involved.

Comment: @YvesDaoust integral of $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$is what i have computed

Comment: @ChristianBlatter i have added a picture

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have edited that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

The area of a circular sector of radius $R$ and aperture $2\alpha$ is

$$\int_{R\cos\alpha}^R2\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\,dx=-\int_\alpha^02\sqrt{R^2-R^2\cos^2\theta}\,R\sin\theta\,d\theta=R^2\int_0^\alpha(1-\cos2\theta)\,d\theta\\
=R^2\alpha-R^2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha.$$

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to integrate. The area of the lens

$$R^2\theta+r^2\alpha-2\times\Delta$$

is just the sum of the areas for the two circle sectors $R^2\theta$ and $r^2\alpha$, minus 2 times the triangle area $\Delta$. You could see this relationship geometrically in a diagram.

The two circle sector are formed from the two intersecting circles of the lens surfaces with radii $R$ and $r$, and sector angles $2\theta$ and $2\alpha$, respectively, and the triangle has the side length $R$, $r$ and $d$.

Comment: can you prove the area of circle sector to be $$radius^2\times\theta$$with calculus ?

Comment: A full circle with $2\pi$ sector angle has an area $\pi a^2$. Then, proportionately, a circle sector with angle $\beta$ has an area $\frac 12 r^2\beta$. In your case, the circle sector angles are $2\theta$ and $2\alpha$.

Comment: see, like we get the result of area of circle with geometry and also with calculus, we should be able to get its area too